# convert bind() mootools to jquery

Tags: jquery, mootools, bind

I have a tiny question : 
I have to convert somme mootools code on jQuery and I have a little question about bind().

I have this on Mootools :

```
$(idString).addEvent('change', function (e) {
        // some things
}.bind(this));
```

And I have converted on jQuery like this :

```
 var self = this;
 $("#" + idString).on('change', function (e) {
        // some things
 }.bind(self));
```

But I'm not sure about the use of bind() or if it's helpful. I think i can remove it but I want to be safe.

Thank you for yours answers

ps : sorry for my (bad) english ^^

Comment: `"#" + idString` - in javascript `+` is the string concatenation operator not `.`

Comment: Right, a little thoughtlessness :)

Comment: since you have passed a reference of your scope object via `self`, you don't need to also bind the function. MooTools' `Function.prototype.bind` is now standard in every ES5 compatible browser so unless you need to support IE8 or test in PhantomJS <= 1.9.x, it's safe to use in jQuery also.